can't install virtualbox in ubuntu24.04LTS because it's not released for this version of ubuntu
I want to install virtualbox on Ubuntu24.04 LTS but I didn't find virtualbox Appropriate package for Ubuntu 24.04 and I downloaded virtualbox for jammy and and try to install it and I get this output
arman@salar:~/Downloads$ sudo apt install ./virtualbox-7.0_7.0.16-162802~Ubuntu~jammy_amd64.deb 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'virtualbox-7.0' instead of './virtualbox-7.0_7.0.16-162802~Ubuntu~jammy_amd64.deb'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 virtualbox-7.0 : Depends: libvpx7 (>= 1.10.0) but it is not installable
                  Recommends: libsdl-ttf2.0-0 but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: gcc but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: make or
                              build-essential but it is not going to be installed or
                              dpkg-dev but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: binutils but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages

is there any way to bypass this error or we have to wait for virtualbox official site to release appropriate package for ubuntu24.04TS ?

There is virtualbox version for 24.04.

Mixing packages from different releases of Ubuntu is an easy way to break your system. Bad idea.

The work around is to install libvpx7 as follows:

Download the file from http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libv/libvpx/libvpx7_1.12.0-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
Install it by running the command sudo apt install ./virtualbox-7.0_7.0.16-162802~Ubuntu~jammy_amd64.deb

(Optional) You can also install libsdl-ttf2.0-0 with: sudo apt install libsdl-ttf2.0-0

VirtualBox (version 7.0.20) in now supported on Ubuntu 24.04.
There is a dedicated Debian file for it.
Link for the same given https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/7.0.20/virtualbox-7.0_7.0.20-163906~Ubuntu~noble_amd64.deb.
This is available on their downloads page.
